# Omission of 8-PSK and 32-QAM in LTE/5GNR

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, amplitude-modulation

In 4G LTE/5G NR, the modulation schemes 8-PSK (which is an intermediate scheme between QPSK and 16 QAM) ,32-QAM (which is in between 16 and 64 QAM) are omitted. If the channel is bad , or the distance increases between user and base station, from 16 QAM, the user/Base station fall back to QPSK. I feel an intermediate modulation scheme should be there, to maintain some decent spectral efficiency ! Any answers ?

Comment: 8-PSK is **not** an intermediate scheme between QPSKand 16-QAM, it is an intermediate scheme between QPSK = 4-PSK and 16-PSK (which was used in the movie "The Martian").

Comment: I'm saying in the channel capacity/spectral efficiency perspective !

Comment: If the channel is "bad" because of general conditions or the distance etc, the channel capacity (in the Shannon sense) is smaller too, and so the channel capacity/spectral efficiency perspective might not change all that much. You need to re-think your question.

Answer (score 2):

Because link adaptation consists of not only modulation order but also channel coding code rate. You can check 38.214 to see that NR [has already covered a wide range of target spectral efficiency](https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/5G/5G_MCS_TBS_CodeRate.html) which allows a very flexible trade-off signaling overhead versus radio link performance. Having something there between is not necessary (yet). FYI we are rather adding 1024QAM for high throughput and some repetition schemes for low throughput use cases respectively.

One could argue that we could nevertheless choose other modulation orders, e.g. 8QAM+32QAM, and still cover a such wide range of target spectral efficiency. It is true, and I *cannot* give an exact answer about this 3GPP choice without digging into the mountain of more-than-14-year-old standardization discussion. However, the current 3GPP selection does offer some nice features, both fundamentally and practically, such as high spectral efficiency (being QAM) and facilitating constellation analysis (being QAM of order $2^m$, I and Q can be seen as two independent random variables), which may be the reasons why the RAN1 people made such a choice.